# Can a keybord app run services like regular app? - android

Tags: android, android-service, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad, custom-keyboard

I want to develop a custom keyboard for android (that can be set on Settings > language and input).
I want the keyboard app to run several services that will be active all the time.
Is it possible?  Can a keyboard app run services like any other app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The answer is yes.  From what I have seen, a custom keyboard app can run multiple services and broadcast receivers.
I hope my question\answer will help somebody in the future.